# Faster way of reading multiple values in Spotfire

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

I am currently using

```
tCursors=tuple(cursors)
for row in myTable.GetRows(tCursors):
    for i in range(0,len(cursors)):
       curValue=cursors[i].CurrentValue
```

to get values from a data table in spotfire. The tuple contains the cursors for all of the columns that I am interested in. Is there a faster way to obtain multiple values from the data table, possibly loading them into an array, or loading the entire data table into a 2d array?

Sorry that this is vague, I am just not sure what options I have to get the data from the spotfire table into python in a format that can be used. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process large data set, you should use **R** (aka *datafunctions*).

**Python** is good to manipulate Spotfire elements thanks to the possibility to modify C# elements with the API.

**R** is good to manipulate data, you can easily perform calculation, aggregation, pivot etc. It is really faster than Ironpython for operations on data.

---

Here are some great resources to help you start with R:

- [The official R documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html)
- [Documentation to manipulate data](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/)

R is widely used, so you can easily find chunks of code on the web to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah I am new to R and i cant find a lot of good documentation for using R with spotfire. So I was trying to find if there was anything that was better with Python. But I will gladly take any good place for documentation for using R with spotfire if you know of any.

Comment: R from Spotfire is not really different from "classic" R. I will edit my answer with some R resources.

Comment: Yeah I mainly meant to how to get things like column properties and what it actually returns.

Comment: Just put them as input or output parameter of your script and you can easily manipulate them in your script, the name of the variable will be the name of your parameter

Comment: Just a note, you can now write Python (yes, base Python, not IronPython) scripts the same way you write TERR scripts. You use libraries/packages the same way you do with TERR as well. If you truly are more comfortable with Python, and are on the right version, you should give this a shot! In this video they actually show it running Tensorflow, which requires reading the data table. https://community.tibco.com/wiki/python-data-function-tibco-spotfire